# Where to install compiled device libraries for functional simulation in Quartus Prime Lite?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm trying to use a vector waveform file in Quartus to conduct a functional simulation on my VHDL design using the simulation waveform tool. However, when I come to run the simulation I get the following error:

```
# ** Error: ORB-SLAM.vho(31): Library maxv not found.
# -- Loading package TEXTIO
# -- Loading package std_logic_1164
# -- Loading package std_logic_arith
# ** Error: ORB-SLAM.vho(34): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "MAXV".
# 
# ** Error: ORB-SLAM.vho(36): VHDL Compiler exiting
# End time: 12:57:23 on Apr 09,2017, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
# Errors: 3, Warnings: 0
# ** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/win32pe_edu/vcom failed.
# Executing ONERROR command at macro ./ORB-SLAM.do line 3

Error.
```

I believe this might have something to do with Modelsim (which is installed on my computer) or Quartus not having the correct libraries installed for the device I am trying to simulate for -which in this case is MAXV. I have some .qdz files for all the devices which I've downloaded from Altera's website and I've installed them in Quartus so I strongly suspect I need to use Quartus' EDA Simulation Library Compiler to compile these files for Modelsim except I don't know where to output them to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you need to compile libraries for MAXV inside Modelsim, just as you would compile any other VHDL (ie no special tool required). Here are the instructions from one of our training courses, which are for compiling **Cyclone IV (not MAXV)**. I could adapt them for MAXV, but that would involve me doing some research, which you could do:

> To simulate the gate-level netlist, you will need to compile the
>   generated simulation model in ModelSim. This references libraries
>   called
>
> ```
> altera
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> cycloneive
> ```
>
> If you are using ModelSim Altera Edition, precompiled version of these
>   libraries are provided and so you can miss out this step. If you are
>   using any other version of Modelsim, you will need to compile these
>   libraries yourself:
>
> Create a new library called `altera`.
>   Compile into this library the following source files, which you will find in the quartus/eda/sim_lib directory of the Quartus
>   installation.
>
> ```
>  altera_primitives_components.vhd
>  altera_primitives.vhd
> ```
>
> Create another new library called `cycloneive`.
>
> Compile into this library the following source files, which you will also find in the `quartus/eda/sim_lib` directory of the Quartus
>   installation.
>
> ```
> cycloneive_atoms.vhd
> cycloneive_components.vhd
> ```

Comment: I know you answered this a while ago, but thanks for your help!